# Performance comparison between react js and Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I have worked in Angular js and find it to be developer friendly and ease of use is awesome. I found out it performs extremely good with SPA(Single page application) architecture and if controller scope variables are not misused.

I however don't know why most of eCommerce companies complaining angular being not performing equivalent to reactjs. I think in lot of use cases might not event found the visible performance difference, with development effort being less.

Angular followed MVC ideology, while React is developed with MVVM design. I don't consider myself a very good programmer in either of them, anyways I have started learning reactjs, so I want to know should I go for react js for my own project or not, one clear advantage is isomorphic rendering.

Comment: It's personal preference really, but *AngularJS* does slow down when it has to watch many objects, which is why *Angular* came about with a completely new architecture. Angular doesn't suffer the same problems as AngularJS' since it doesn't have a digest cycle going up and down the entire DOM tree, potentially multiple times.

Comment: There are plenty of articles online on this topic, and you'd mostly see that Angular JS is much slower than React. Though, with Angular 2, things are close AFAIK. But what's your question anyway? Do you expect people to post their own experience? Because that's going to generate opinionated content. Otherwise, you can search for benchmarks online yourself.

Comment: that's what I assume, people who has used both of them .. I know there is a bunch of articles out there, but sometimes personal references where stack-overflow as a platform might help me .. In this case I am certain I would like to try angular 2 first and then probably move things to react js thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make this a comment but ran out of space :)

As with anything, it is as fast as the developer can make it :) A good AngularJS developer can make an app that is faster than a bad developer creating a React app.

Having said that, React will be faster out of the box with a LARGE amount of elements on screen.  AngularJS will require some knowledge to make it fast with lots of on screen elements.  But I fully expect for most people they won't ever see any performance drop with most apps. E.g. if you want to make a fairly complex application with a couple of hundred dynamic objects on screen you shouldn't see many performance problems.

If you do choose AngularJS [my preferred framework] I would suggest following the latest component guidelines as it will help you build a performant application.

As an indicator I am working on an asset tracking AngularJS app.  We can track around 2000 elements on screen a map at once with lots of additional information and this works pretty fast. It took a lot of work to get there though. It also works great on mobile too :)